# boost::thread_group in C++11?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-thread

Is there anything like `boost::thread_group` in C++11?

I'm just trying to port my program from using `boost:thread` to C++11 threads and wasn't able to find anything equivalent.

Comment: Boost threads and C++11 threads are different. I personally keep using boost threads because of the more complete API (and the lack of current implementation of eg. thread local storage).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, there's nothing directly equivalent to `boost::thread_group` in C++11. You could use a `std::vector<std::thread>` if all you want is a container. You can then use either the new `for` syntax or `std::for_each` to call `join()` on each element, or whatever.

Comment: Since 2012 has there been a better solution to this problem?

Comment: I'd like to add that there is really no magic in `boost::thread_group`, it's a little more than a vector of threads (the "little more" being some utility functions like `join_all` and `create_thread`).

Answer (score 11):

`thread_group` didn't make it into C++11, C++14, C++17 or C++20 standards.

But a workaround is simple:

```
  std::vector<std::thread> grp;

  // to create threads
  grp.emplace_back(functor); // pass in the argument of std::thread()

  void join_all() {
    for (auto& thread : grp)
        thread.join();
  }
```

Not even worth wrapping in a class (but is certainly possible).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to C++20, then you can use `std::vector` and [std::jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) instead of [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)  to create a group of threads.

If you use `std::jthread` then no need to call `join()` on each thread. `jthread` automatically calls `join()` upon destruction.

Here is a working example:

https://godbolt.org/z/o9rPfd4zn

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    constexpr int count = 3;
    std::vector<std::jthread> thread_group;

    for( int i = 1; i <= count; ++i )
    {
        thread_group.emplace_back([i=i](){ 
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(i)); 
            std::cout << " Thread " << i << " finished." << std::endl;
            });
    }
    // no need to join the threads here
}
```